# Nao consigo utilizar as Pseudo-classes no css

Tags: css, css-hover

Olá.
Estou tentando colocar um estilo nos links do meu site, mas quando abro o site não aplica as alterações que coloquei através do css.
Utilizei o seguinte código

[image: erro pseudo-class]

Já pesquisei em alguns lugares, mas nenhum informa o meu prblema.

Comment: Procure oferecer a maior quantidade de detalhes que puder sobre o seu problema e de preferência opte sempre por compartilhar o código em vez de imagens, @Matheus. Assim será mais fácil aos usuários oferecer qualquer tipo de auxilio.

Comment: Porque falta um `;` (ponto e vírgula) na linha 7

Answer (score 1):

Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow!

Utilizei exatamente o mesmo css que você disponibilizou e esta funcionando normalmente.
A unica diferença é um `;` que estava faltando na linha `7` em `color: #315e8a`

```css
body {
  font-family: "K2D", sans-serif;
}

a:link, a:active, a:visited {
  color: #315e8a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#teste">Teste</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não testei o código, mas tem um ponto e vírgula (;) faltando na linha 7. Tente isso e provavelmente vai funcionar.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/191794)

Comment: Mas não depende de mais informações, o erro só pode ser esse.